# android, how to pop a dialog from some non ui module

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog

How to open a dialog when from some non ui module when there might be different activity in display?

Let's say there could be multiple activities stacked, Activity_A, Activity_B, Activity_C. The common service module may running on non ui thread and running into case need to popup a dialog.

It could be done by passing the handler from all active activities to the module and post message to let the activity to pop dialog.

But that need some management in terms of passing the handler and determine who is on top of the view.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Implement the interface for it when service need to show the dialog.

Comment: Thanks Abdul! That has similar problem to resolve that is to which activity to call and manage the who's on top? A simpler solution would be better.

Comment: you will also try to use observer design pattern as well.

Comment: what your try post here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After try out I think the simplest is to use application context to open a activity for dialog. This way it would not care who's the current activity on top.

```
Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(applicationCotext, DialogActivity.class);
    dialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    applicationCotext.startActivity(dialogIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can show dailog from non-ui thread using `BroadcastReceiver`

**Understand Flow:**

```
public class Sample extends Activity {

    BroadcastReceiver updateUIReciver;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        updateUIReciver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                //UI update here
                ShowFailedDailog(null, getString(R.string.mms_sending_service_failed_txt));
            }
        };
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction("update.from.nonui");
        registerReceiver(updateUIReciver, filter);
    }

    void ShowFailedDailog(String title, String message) {
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.import_backup_popup);

        TextView Save = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tOk);
        Save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        TextView cancel = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tCancel);
        cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        dialog.show();
    }
}
```

**NON UI:**

```
public class NonUiSerive extends Service {
     Context context;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if (intent != null) {

            // ..... your tasks

            if (SomeFlagUpdateTrue) {
                Intent local = new Intent();
                local.setAction("mms.seding.failed");
                context.sendBroadcast(local);
            }
        }
        this.stopSelf();
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Similarly register receiver all your three class it will update in every activity not restricted to one.

Comment: Thanks Sohail!, Similar issue that which activity should handle it since not knowing which one is on top, and not really want use broadcast service. The Abdul's interface face approach could achieve same. Good option though.